# Why does this phase calculation go to 180 instead of 90?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, laplace-transform, control-theory

This is all coming from the following video I am studying from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XSS6L42ce88

So I am working from this system
$$ G(s)\,=\,\frac{4}{s^{2}+s+2}$$

and the video states the gain and phase equations for it are as follows (I agree with this bit)

$$ |G(j\omega)| = \frac{4}{\sqrt{\omega^{2} + (2-\omega^{2})^{2}}} $$
and
$$\angle G(j\omega)\,=\,-\arctan\left(\frac{\omega}{2-\omega^{2}}\right)$$

Okay so I want to see what the gain and phase do when the omega tends to zero.

So obviously the gain term will end up being **2** and the phase will be **0 degrees**

**Now here is the bit I am struggling with**
The video then says let's see what the function does as omega tends to infinity.

So the gain term will end up being $4/\infty = 0$ but it says the phase will go to **-180 degrees** (it says that at 02:39 http://youtu.be/XSS6L42ce88?t=2m39s)

Now from how I see it, the phase term at infinity will end up being 
$$-\arctan\left(\frac{\infty}{2-\infty^{2}}\right) $$ Which as I see it is a very large negative number so shouldn't the phase be **-90 or 90 degrees not -180 degrees**

I think I have heard about this before and it's to do with being in the wrong quadrant but I am confused as hell. I have really tried with this plugging in all sorts of values.

Comment: Your error is that you're "plugging in" infinity. Instead, we need to see what happens in the limit of $\frac{\omega}{2-\omega^2}$ as we increase $\omega$ to infinity. In fact, for very large values of $\omega$, $\frac{\omega}{2-\omega^2}$ looks pretty much like $-\frac{\omega}{\omega^2} \sim -\frac{1}{\omega}$, which tends to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the breaking point, that is at $\sqrt2$. If you calculate the phase in this point, you can see that is equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

When you consider $\omega$ to $0$ or $\infty$, is just a convention that you consider the first result $0$ as $0$, and the second as $-\pi$ (the minus comes from the fact that it's to the denominator)

---

Let's see a generic quadratic function:
$$[(\frac{j\omega}{\omega_n})^2+2\zeta\frac{j\omega}{\omega_n}+1]^{\pm 1}$$

Where $\omega_n$ is the breaking point.
If we separate the imaginary part from the real, we obtain:
$$[(1-\frac{\omega^2}{\omega^2_n})+(2\zeta\frac{j\omega}{\omega_n})]^{\pm 1}$$

Now, when you calculate the phase you have to start from the breaking point (because is the middle point between the result for $\omega \to 0$ and $\omega \to \infty$.

In your example you have: 
$$[(1-\frac{\omega^2}{(\sqrt2)^2})+(2(\frac{\sqrt2}{2})\frac{j\omega}{\sqrt2})]^{- 1}$$

The phase is:
$$\phi= -\tan^{-1} \frac{2(\frac{\sqrt2}{2})\frac{j\omega}{\sqrt2}}{1-\frac{\omega^2}{(\sqrt2)^2}}$$

Thet becomes for the breaking point ($\omega=\sqrt2$):
$$\phi= -\tan^{-1} \frac{\sqrt2}{1-1}= -tan^{-1} \infty = -\pi/2$$

So, in that point the phase is -$\pi/2$. Now if you consider the two extremis you obtain both $\phi=0$. You choose $0$ for $\omega \to 0$ and $-\pi$ for $\omega \to \infty$ because a convention.

Why this convention? It's possibile understand it by this:
if we plot a generic $x \mapsto 1-x^2-j 2 \zeta x$  we obtain
[image]

Where you can see that the phase converges to $-\pi$ as $x \to \infty$.
And you can also see that the phase for $x=0$ (which corresponds to $1-0j$) is zero.

Comment: Hi.. I feel like you almost have me on the right track to understand what you are saying... Do you mind going a little bit more in depth coz I'm a bit I confused at the minute,.. Thanks if so

Comment: I added something else, try to see if it's more clear. Ask if it's not.

Comment: After reading your answer I went and discovered the arctan2 function, so if I have this correct the, arctan function will only work between +/- pi/2 so that is where I was going wrong, whereas the arctan2 function will take care of the quadrant? thanks for the help I never knew about this stuff

Comment: With the arctan2 function you consider in the calculus both the imaginary and real part of the original function. You have to consider the entire circumference when you are computing about angles. Here a link with an explanation of the function for Matlab: http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html

Answer (score 1):

As $\omega\to \infty$, the argument ${\omega}/(2-\omega^2)$ will also go to zero, not infinity (since the bottom grows quadratically and the top only linearly).  Hence 90 or -90 is not an option.